# Grails url mapping 404 not redirecting

Tags: angularjs, grails, url-mapping

Is there something else to configure for url mapping to get it working ?

When I type a wrong url in the browser the Chrome console show the error

```
GET http://localhost:8081/aaa 404 (Not Found)
```

EDIT:

and in the Grails console I see :

```
INFO  myApp.ProjectController  - Entering Action /project/index
```

But no redirection is doing to the `error.gsp` view. I tried to change with : `"404"(view:'/')` with no success.

**Notice** *I use Angularjs in that project but only in one page for the moment.*

Thanks for your help

```
UrlMappings.groovy
    class UrlMappings {
        static mappings = {
            "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
                constraints {
                    // apply constraints here
                }
            }
            "404"(view:'/error')
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that your app is mapped to ROOT context? to `http://localhost:8081/`? Grails is usually mapped to `http://localhost:8081/appname/`, see last line in server console

Comment: Yes I'am shure. It is set in my Config.groovy : `grails.app.context = '/'` and my app is showing on `http://localhost:8081/`

Comment: Are there any plugins in your app?

Comment: A grails clean + compile and its working.